# Java: Massive Class Collision

Tags: java, maven, hbase

I am working on a web service that talks to Apache HBase.  The HBase Maven artifact contains all sorts of web libraries, such as `jersey-core`, but I am using Apache CXF.  When I compile and run my app, I get a huge list of JarClassLoader warnings.  The result is I cannot **initialize** my class that contains my HBase Connection.

```
$ java -jar target/myapp.one-jar.jar
JarClassLoader: Warning: Null manifest from input stream associated with: lib/javax.inject-1.jar
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.class in lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/Buffer.class in lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/BufferUnderflowException.class in lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$1.class in lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$CollectionView$CollectionViewIterator.class in lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$CollectionView.class in lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$EntrySet.class in lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$KeySet.class in lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$Values.class in lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap.class in lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanAccessLanguageException.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/beanutils/locale/LocaleBeanUtils$Descriptor.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaProperty.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
...
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/commons/beanutils/LazyDynaClass.class in lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is hidden by lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/Filter.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/FilterChain.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/FilterConfig.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/GenericServlet.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/http/Cookie.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
...
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/Filter.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/FilterChain.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/FilterConfig.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/GenericServlet.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/http/Cookie.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.class in lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar is hidden by lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar (with different bytecode)
... 
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/jasper/EmbeddedServletOptions.class in lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar is hidden by lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/jasper/JspC.class in lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar is hidden by lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/jasper/JspCompilationContext.class in lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar is hidden by lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/jasper/Options.class in lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar is hidden by lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/jasper/compiler/BeanRepository.class in lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar is hidden by lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/jasper/compiler/Collector$CollectVisitor.class in lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar is hidden by lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/jasper/compiler/Collector.class in lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar is hidden by lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/jasper/compiler/Compiler.class in lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar is hidden by lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/jasper/compiler/DefaultErrorHandler.class in lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar is hidden by lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: org/apache/jasper/compiler/Dumper$DumpVisitor.class in lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar is hidden by lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar (with different bytecode)
...
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/ws/rs/Path.class in lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar is hidden by lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.class in lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar is hidden by lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/ws/rs/core/Application.class in lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar is hidden by lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/ws/rs/core/CacheControl.class in lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar is hidden by lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/ws/rs/core/Cookie.class in lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar is hidden by lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/ws/rs/core/EntityTag.class in lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar is hidden by lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar (with different bytecode)
JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.class in lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar is hidden by lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar (with different bytecode)
```

And my app blows up how do I fix this?

Comment: The short answer is you need to go through your classpath and resolve the problems.  A quick skim shows you're calling for different versions of the same jars.  Most of the time you can resolve that by simply calling for the newer version in all locations but you'll have to go through and verify everything works

Comment: the thing is, these are dependencies being brought in by the hbase jar.  There is only one jar.  How do I selectively cherry pick its components?

Comment: There shouldn't be collisions within the same jar.  Where is this jar coming from?

Comment: HBase, it brings in many dependencies.    http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase/0.94.11